# What is this extra wire in my light fixture box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

House built in the early 70's. Yesterday, I had to unmount a few light fixtures in my hall. The three lights are all controlled (as a single group) by three different wall switches. The fixtures are newer vintage and the bases are very lightweight, so I left them hanging by their electrical leads connected to wire nuts. One of them was not well connected to the wire nuts, and the black leads pulled out. The white ones remained connected and supported the weight.

When I went to connect the fixture and remount it, I noticed an extra black wire coming from the box. I assumed it went with the other black fixture leads in the wire nut. I had the breaker switched off so I was surprised to get a zap from one of the mounting screws when trying to work with the wires. I also noticed that when the "extra" black wire was connected to the fixture, the light bulb flickered dimly. I moved the extra wire aside and connected the light fixture to the other black lead (the one still in the wire nut). Flipped the breaker on and all the lights works fine. After that, I noticed another wire nut and bundle of black wires up in the box (picture below). Can anyone tell me if the extra wire belongs there? I really appreciate any help anyone can provide.

[image: Light fixture box]

[image: Diagram]

[image: Switch Box 1]

[image: Switch Box 2]

[image: Switch Box 3]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. That wire popped out of a wire nut (note the curl at the end), but we can't tell which one from here; perhaps a diagram would help? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: @DanielGriscom we can’t assume that the curl was there before 0p bundled it in with the others in the failed attempt to find its home.

Comment: Check to see if there are any outlets or lights that are not working.

Comment: Some old homes ran a separate wire to individual sockets in a fixture. This was a primitive method for turning a light on from different locations.

Comment: I added a diagram of the wiring above. The extra wire was curled before I attempted to use it a wire nut. Have not found any lights or outlets that are not working. Also, one correction to my original post: There are 3 light switches, but only 2 fixtures. I realized after I posted that the 3rd light in the hall has its own switch.

Comment: Is it some sort of wild MWBC?

Comment: @drewns, do you mean this is controlled by a set of three way switches?  Meaning you can turn it on from one switch and turn it off from a different switch, like staircase lights?

Comment: @NateS., yes that is correct. 3 different three-way switches. Any of them can be used to turn the lights on/off.

Comment: @drewns, given that, plus the fact that there's no /3 cable anywhere in there (which would have a red wire, and normally would be required for 3 way switching), I think probably whoever did this originally ran out of /3 cable and used 2x /2 cables in parallel instead.  That's a code violation, and it makes this extra hard to figure out -- we're probably also going to need pictures of how all the switches are wired to make sense of this.

Comment: @NateS., I've added photos of the switch boxes above. The second and third are double-gang boxes, but in both cases the switch on the right is for a separate, independently switched single light fixture. Only the left switches are three-way switches that control the fixtures in question. Thank you again to anyone who can provide insight. I'm not an electrician, and this is over my head. It's frustrating because if I'd paid close attention before the wire came unhooked I could have just hooked it back up! Live and learn!

Comment: @drewns Don't worry, "taking pictures before I disconnected everything" is the answer to about 50% of the electrical questions around here. You're not alone!

Comment: Also, I note that your switches are all upside down and that they don't have grounds connected. (They're 3-way switches, so they're not labeled "On"/"Off", but normally the ground screw goes on the bottom.) If the electricians that installed this couldn't be bothered to hook up ground wires, I wonder what other short cuts they took in your house...

Comment: @FreeMan, The "electricians that installed this" are me :)  I replaced these switches and wall plates about a year ago. I did not know about the grounding screw typically being at the bottom, so thank you for that tip! I definitely did install the switches exactly like the old ones, without a grounding wire, so you may be right about "short cuts" a previous electrician may have made. I will note that all of the plugs I've replaced DO have a grounding wire connected.

Comment: _gulp!_ Thanks for taking that in the right spirit, @drewns!

Comment: Funny freeman, I have seen 3 ways done like that (separate cables) start flipping switches until it won’t work and that helps to narrow it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to follow up with the correct answer for anyone who might find this thread in the future. We're in the middle of a kitchen/dining remodel, so I waited until the electricians were here for their rough-in and asked them about this hall fixture. One little detail I forgot to mention regarding the two wires from the pipe: The pipe is "filled" with some kind of black solid or foam. Turns out the two wires from the pipe should have been twisted together, but there was no wire nut for them, and they were not making a good connection. This made our DOORBELL not work. It has not worked for the 7 years we've lived at this house. Directly above the ceiling box (in the attic) was the transformer for the doorbell. I've looked for it a bit in the past so I could repair/replace it, but was never able to find it. Also, the electrician noted that the hall light circuit was sharing a neutral with a kitchen circuit. They said that was not ideal, and fixed it.

So in summary, in addition to its normal ceiling box duties, this box was doubling as a junction box for the doorbell transformer AND doubling as a junction box for a kitchen circuit. Mystery solved. Thank you everyone that contributed!

Comment: Wow... that's a busy little JB! Thanks for coming back to let us know. Be sure to give yourself a check mark on this answer, so that others will know it's been resolved.